# Go to the slide page you want in ionic5 ion-slide

Tags: ionic-framework, slide, swiper.js, ionic5

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let d of data">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="contents">
          <ion-col class="no">{{d.index}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col class="title">{{d.title}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Can I jump to the slide on the page I want when I click a button on the ionic slide?

For example, there are 15 slides in total.

I'm on the 1st slide, and I want to jump to the 10th slide at once when the button is clicked.
Is that feature an implementable feature?

If a feature is possible, please let me know how.

(ps. How to go to id by adding id value to slide?)

Comment: Maybe a slider is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to use the slides to make an ebook form.

Comment: You can use ngif to toggle the visibility to slides. When user clicks button, all other slides are toggled visibility off and only the one required have visibility turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use api slideTo on slides compoment
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-jackson-l30so?file=/src/About.vue